# Is Winsock error 10054 (WSAECONNRESET) "normal" with UDP to/from localhost?

Tags: udp, winsock

"What could possibly go wrong with using UDP for inter-process communications on a single Windows PC?" I thought... and proceeded to implement it.

But despite sending mere hundreds of bytes and only very sporadically, and also despite UDP being used as a connectionless protocol (`sendto()` function employed), I am plagued by random occurrences of error 10054 - "connection reset". I find this very confusing. Is it:

- perfectly normal, to be expected, in which case... what does it mean has happened?
- completely unexpected, and I've probably implemented something wrong
- completely unexpected, so I should check for conflicting software (e.g. for [problems like this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981344))
- something else?

I read somewhere that it could indicate that there is no receiving port open at the other end... but this makes even less sense to me - isn't UDP simply supposed to send the datagram off and not care what happens to it? Or is there some special case when the send occurs to/from ports on the same machine (localhost)?

Comment: It is completely unexpected, period. It's a TCP condition. The UDP error when the target doesn't exist is ECONNREFUSED, and it is only delivered when you're connected.

Comment: On further investigation it appears Windows may return ECONNRESET when there is nothing listening at the target, instead of ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: @EJP - Can you provide the source of that further investigation? Because it sounds like a weird thing to do in conjunction with UDP.

Comment: It appears that the Windows recvfrom documentation might hold the answer... to be confirmed.

Comment: Even though UDP is connection-less, there can be ICMP packets sent in the background to let a UDP sender know when a receiver is not available, and WinSock interprets those packets internally and can cause higher-level socket functions to fail. For instance, as documented for `recvfrom()`: "*WSAECONNRESET - The virtual circuit was reset by the remote side executing a hard or abortive close. The application should close the socket; it is no longer usable. **On a UDP-datagram socket this error indicates a previous send operation resulted in an ICMP Port Unreachable message**.*" ...

Comment: ... and documented for `sendto()`: "*WSAECONNRESET - 
The virtual circuit was reset by the remote side executing a hard or abortive close. **For UPD sockets, the remote host was unable to deliver a previously sent UDP datagram and responded with a "Port Unreachable" ICMP packet**. The application should close the socket as it is no longer usable.*"

Comment: Googling this error gives me lots of gitlab / github issues related to ECONREFUSED for UDP and quite a few people wondering what "connection" even means in this case... that late ICMP packet is such a confusing "feature" to add. Why does this concept even belong in UDP? If I wanted a connected API I'd use TCP or an API that simulates connections with UDP.

Answer (score 1):

In my specific case, I had a server running on localhost listening on a UDP socket bound to a specific port. It also had a second UDP socket bound to the same port (it makes sense in context), used only for sending responses to the packets received on the first socket.

Clients, also running on localhost, would create a temporary socket, send a packet to the server, wait for a response, then close their socket. The timeout on the client side was very short (for application-specific reasons), with a retry if the initial attempt timed out.

What would happen on occasion is a client would send a packet to the server, time out before the response could be sent, and close its socket. The server would then receive (on the listening socket) the packet from the client, and send back a response (on the sending socket). However, Windows "helpfully" sends back an ICMP response stating that there's no longer any socket listening on the destination port. Crucially, this packet ends up being delivered to the listening socket, and not to the sending socket (since they both share the same port). On the next read from the listening socket on the server receives a `WSAECONNRESET` error indicating the previous packet it sent (which was actually sent from a different socket) failed to get delivered.

In my case, **the fix was simply to ignore `WSAECONNRESET` errors** on the listening socket. The listening socket continued to successfully receive other packets after such errors occurred, and the sending socket continued to successfully send packets after a packet failed to get delivered.

Comment: Why the second socket? What's wrong with sending via the original socket?

Comment: Nothing, except that the port that the second socket is sending from is sometimes different, and the client uses the source port of the response to configure itself.