# Swift UDP Connection Refused

Tags: swift, udp

```swift
func send(_ payload: Data) {
        connection!.send(content: payload, completion: .contentProcessed({ sendError in
            if let error = sendError {
                NSLog("Unable to process and send the data: \(error)")
            } else {
                NSLog("Data has been sent")
                connection!.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
                    if(isComplete){
                        guard let myData = data else { return }
                        NSLog("Received message: " + String(decoding: myData, as: UTF8.self))
                    }else{
                        NSLog("XYITA")
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
    }
```

So, I got this send function, connection works fine, connection.send works fine, but *connection.receiveMessage* throws strange error, which I cannot find how to resolve.

Error:
**[connection] nw_socket_get_input_frames [C1:1] recvmsg(fd 17, 9216 bytes) [61: Connection refused]**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly related to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749423/is-winsock-error-10054-wsaeconnreset-normal-with-udp-to-from-localhost